# How to Fix MySQL When I'm Login Getting Error?

Tags: mysql

I am able to log in to mysql using the path

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

But when I type in `mysql -uroot -p` and type in my password I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Trying to figure out why it still prompts me for a password but fires back an error? is it possible I have two separate mysql installed or is the command `mysql -uroot -p` not set up correctly

```
Andress-MacBook-Pro:~ alpha$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Andress-MacBook-Pro:~ alpha$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 22
Server version: 8.0.17 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.


Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I'm expecting the same successful log in with the simpler command of `mysql -uroot -p`

Comment: You apparently have two versions of `mysql` installed. What does `type mysql` show?

Comment: When I enter "type mysql" in command line I get back "mysql is hashed (/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql"

Comment: So you have two copies of MySQL installed, one is part of MAMP, the other is in `/usr/local`. And somehow both servers are running. You know the password for the `/usr/local` copy, but not the MAMP copy. You need to fix your installation, getting rid of one of them.

Comment: Thanks Barmar I got rid of the /usr/local one using the steps described here https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d though I did not have "homebrew" I think I got it all out.. Thas a mil